# SQL Query for Total Orders per Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query in SQL that calculated the total in orders (dollar amount) per month for the current year.

My table is setup this way:

```
OrderID      OrderTotal       OrderDate
5598745      85.70            2016-07-29
5598744      184.75            2016-07-25
5598743      847.50            2016-06-20
5598742      50.00            2016-06-05
```

So my query should display something like this:

```
June $897.50
July $270.45
etc...
```

I'm working with this without success:

```
SELECT 
  month(OrderDate) AS month_name, 
  SUM(OrderTotal) AS sum_of_month, 
  AVG(SUM(OrderTotal)) OVER () AS avg_sum 
FROM 
  [db].[dbo].[orders] 
WHERE 
  YEAR(OrderDate) = YEAR(GetDate())
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you just need to add a `GROUP BY MONTH(OrderDate)`

Comment: you need to group it by month

Answer (score 1):

for month sum you should use group by

```
SELECT month(OrderDate) AS month_name, 
        SUM(OrderTotal) AS sum_of_month
        AVG(OrderTotal) AS AVG_of_month
FROM [db].[dbo].[orders] 
WHERE YEAR(OrderDate) = YEAR(GetDate())
GROUP BY month(OrderDate);
```

Comment: also, select and group by year as well: YEAR(OrderDate), month(OrderDate)

Comment: you need to add the year to the select clause @scaisEdge

Comment: @trincot  normally in SQL is possible  group by for a not selecting column .. the restriction si for order by .. usually

Comment: @scaisEdge perfect!

Comment: @Brasciole  thanks  .. if my answer is what you are looking for  .. please mark it as accepted .

Answer (score 1):

> **Use DateName() to get the Month's name**

```
Declare @Table table (OrderTotal money,OrderDate Date)
Insert into @Table values
(85.70,'2016-07-29'),
(184.75,'2016-07-25'),
(847.50,'2016-06-20'),
(50.00,'2016-06-05')

 Select MonthName=DateName(MM,OrderDate)
       ,Total=sum(OrderTotal)
     From  @Table
     Where Year(OrderDate) = Year(GetDate())
     Group By Month(OrderDate),DateName(MM,OrderDate)
     Order By Month(OrderDate)
```

Returns

```
MonthName   Total
June        897.50
July        270.45
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may work

```
SELECT 
  month(OrderDate) AS month_name, 
  SUM(OrderTotal) AS sum_of_month, 
  AVG(SUM(OrderTotal)) OVER () AS avg_sum 
FROM 
  [db].[dbo].[orders] 
WHERE 
  YEAR(OrderDate) = YEAR(GetDate())
order by  month(OrderDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple query for computing sum for every month.

```
select datename(month, dateadd(month, month(OrderDate), 0) - 1) as month_name, 
   sum(OrderTotal) as sum_of_month 
   from Orders
where year(OrderDate) = year(getdate())
group by month(OrderDate)
order by month(OrderDate)
```

It seems that you want to obtain an average of all the sums. I don't think that it is a good idea to present it in this table. The same number would be presented for each row. Instead I recommend a separate query:

```
select avg(t.month_sum) from 
    (select sum(OrderTotal) as month_sum from Orders 
     where year(OrderDate) = year(getdate()) 
     group by month(OrderDate)
    ) as t
```